# Print numpy output in textbox Tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

I have written a code to create a GUI with Tkinter. In this GUI i can open an image and run a code that gives me the mean RGB value of that image:

```
 x = image[np.all(image != 0, axis=2)].mean(axis=0)
```

At this moment I can only print the value in the shell. The next step is that I want to print the 'R' the 'G' and the 'B' in a different textboxes.
I know how to create a textbox, but I don't know how to print the different values in this textbox.

Thanks

Comment: This problem can be split into subproblems like: Creating a tkinter window, creating a text box inside that window, inserting the text inside the text box, getting the data out of the numpy array, and rounding the numbers to 1 decimal place. Please ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: I adapted the question, the most important question is how to put my values into the textboxes

Comment: Do you know how to separate the RGB Value? If yes, it will be easier to answer. Or else, we will need to explain a lot

Comment: My idea was to create a dataframe in excel with the RGB value and print the Excel cell in the textbox. But i guess there will be a better way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put the values in `x` inside three `Entry` widgets?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to put the values in `x` into three `Entry` widgets, below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

...

x = image[np.all(image != 0, axis=2)].mean(axis=0)

root = tk.Tk()
for color, value in zip("RGB", x):
    tk.Label(root, text=color).pack(side="left")
    e = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
    e.pack(side="left")
    e.insert("end", f"{value:.4f}")
root.mainloop()
```

And the sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To print output to a Tkinter textbox, it as simple as this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

mytext = Text(root)
mytext.insert(INSERT, 'my amazing text')
mytext.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will return:

[image]